# Is SCP Ant task thread safe

Tags: multithreading, ant, scp

We have multiple servers that we need to get files out to. We're using Ant based build system and to save up some time we're trying to deploy them to each of the boxes in a separate thread:

`<for param="file" parallel="true" threadCount="10">
...
<sequential>
<sshexec host="${host}" trust="true" username="${username}" password="${password}" command="do some setup;"/>
<scp todir="${username}:${password}@${host}:~/" trust="true" >
    <fileset dir="${releaseDir}/..">
        <include name="releases/**" />
    </fileset>
</scp>

...
</sequential>
</for>`

This snippet fails intermittently for some boxes but works fine using a single thread - which leads me to believe that it doesn't handle multithreading well.

1.Has anyone come across similar issue?
2.Can you recommend any alternatives?

Comment: as an alternative, you could try with `ftp` ant task : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ftp.html . Not sure why it is failing though it is within `seqeuntial` block for you..

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Unfortunatelly FTP is a no go - our security policies rule that out :(